# Sending HTML emails in Outlook 2010 without MailChimp

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have created my HTML email in an index.html file and linked all the images to an FTP site.

I am not using MailChimp etc, I want to know how to send this email directly from Outlook 2010 itself?

How can I send this email out to lots of people (all using Outlook) and for them to be able to view the HTML within the email itself and not opening an attachment.

I basically want the code I have done in the body of the email within Outlook?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Its been a while since Ive done this myself but if you create a new mail message and then choose Insert, then File and finally select your coded HTML file. In the lower right corner of the Insert dialog click on the arrow next to the insert button and select Insert as Text.

The other option would be to import the HTML file itself as stationery. Here is Microsoft's walkthrough of that process:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-stationery-for-email-messages-HA102561327.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010355037